# How to fix System.UnauthorizedAccessException error when trying to open Onedrive file picker?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I created a JS client in order to call onedrive filepicker with [OneDrive file picker for JavaScript v7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/js-v72/?view=odsp-graph-online)
it works fine with my domain but when I try it with an other domain, when calling /me it returns System.UnauthorizedAccessException error.

Here is the code :

```
const options = {
    clientId: g__app_ms_client_id,
    action: 'query',
    viewType: 'folders',
    advanced: {
      redirectUri: `${g__site_url}action/one_drive`,
    },
    success(files) {

    },
    cancel() {

    },
    error(error) {

    },
  };

  OneDrive.open(options);
```

and the error returned :

```
Error: graph/me request failed, status code: '403'
```

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
    "message": "Accès refusé. Vous n’êtes pas autorisé à effectuer cette action ou à accéder à cette ressource.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "072ae26a-38bc-42dd-9bdc-0c5005a3ddda",
      "date": "2019-09-04T15:04:12"
    }
  }
}
```

I expect it opens a filepicker.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you need a public client registration.

There is an example of the OneDrive picker here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-smartui-components/tree/master/Demos/01-pickers